# How to resolve issue with web application not able to authenticate to database deployed to Azure SQL

Tags: authentication, azure-sql-database

I have a web application developed in .net 4.8.1 that uses an API also developed in .net 4.8.1, and the API makes a connection to a SQL database for both authentication and data access. If I connect the API to a local instance of SQL Server everything works fine. The web app makes the call to Authenticate and the API performs the authentication just fine. Just changing the database connection to an Azure instance of the database causes the authentication process to fail with an "internal server error". No specifics are given for what the error is, it just fails.

I have verified that my system can successfully access the Azure SQL server using SSMS (I have added my local IP to the firewall settings on Azure for the database).The database on Azure contains the same data as my local instance of the database. Because I can't find any information on the cause of the failure I don't know where to look or try to resolve this. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: could you please provide the sample error and the way how you connect to the database to web application with connectionstring?

Comment: The error that is thrown is: The entity type ApplicationUser is not part of the model for the current context.  I am making the connection with the following connection string:  <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="metadata=res://*/MyModel.csdl|res://*/MyModel.ssdl|res://*/MyModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=tcp:myserver.database.windows.net,1433;initial catalog=<mydb>;persist security info=True;user id=<user>;password=<pwd>;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />

Comment: The call to Authenticate is as follows:  public AuthData Authenticate(string username, string pass)
 {
  var clientInfo = Skyline.Common.Clients.Get("MyClient");
  string body = $"grant_type=password&client_id={clientInfo.ID}&client_secret={clientInfo.Secret}&username={username}&password={pass}";
  string path = "Token";            
  var stringContent = new StringContent(body, Encoding.UTF8, "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
  HttpResponseMessage response = _httpClient.PostAsync(path, stringContent).Result;
  return ProcessAuthResponse(response);
 }

Comment: Does anyone have any suggestions or can I supply information to assist in getting an answer?